# How to override tableview delegate in XCTest

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, xctestcase

How to write a testcase for this "success" scenario?

```
if ([tblView.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:)]) {
         ...
}else{
         ...
}
```

I have tried by creating the below mock delegate in swift:

```
class MockTableViewDelegate:NSObject, UITableViewDelegate {

  @objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 30
        }

        // MARK: Delegates
   @objc func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            return UIView()
        }
}
```

**Code:**

```
mockTableView.delegate=MockTableViewDelegate()  
print("delegate===\(mockTableView.delegate)")
```

It prints nil. The same mockup I have tried for the datasource and it is returning the datasource obj. Why delegate is returning nil? and how to test this scenario?

Comment: Is `tblView.delegate` non nil in the if? If non-nil, is its type `MockTableViewDelegate`?

Comment: is the tblView's delegate property set via Storyboard or Code? The time and  context play important role in the delegate and datasource properties. At what point is the test case run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found this is a bug in the iOS runtime. The one way to solve this problem is to use OCMock, but its not available for Swift. So I have written in Objective-c for now.

```
UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];
UIView *headerView = [UIView new];

id delegateProtocolMock = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(UITableViewDelegate));
tableView.delegate=delegateProtocolMock;
OCMStub([delegateProtocolMock tableView:tableView viewForHeaderInSection:0]).andReturn(headerView);
```

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are usually weak references. If you assign your `MockTableViewDelegate` to a local variable first it should still be alive when used in `print`. Try the following:

```
let delegate = MockTableViewDelegate()
mockTableView.delegate = delegate
print("delegate===\(mockTableView.delegate)")
print(delegate)
```

The fourth line is required to keep the object living for the third line.

Comment: Tried no luck. I think this is same as what i have posted.

Comment: what is the type of mockTableView? If it's not UITableView, then have you done something to the delegate property?

Comment: This might also not hold the weak reference because you aren't using delegate either.  Add `print("delegate===\(delegate)")` to the bottom.  If that works, add a delegate member property to the test case.

Comment: @LouFranco is right. If you don't use `delegate` after the third line it might get deallocated after the second line. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I guess its swift issue.  because i tried the same for datasource and its working. eg:1. let delegate = MockTableViewDelegate()
2. mockTableView.delegate = delegate 3. mockTableView.datasource = delegate.